# Visibility of JavaScript varaibles when using getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My webpage consist of multiple javascript files, which I dynamically load via the JQuery instruction `$.getScript(...)`. But I noticed some behaviour which I can't understand.

For example assume `myScript1.js` looks like this:

```
var a;
var b;

function ab() {
    a=1;
    b=2;
}
```

If I now do the following inside `anotherScript.js`, I will get the following logs:

```
$.getScript("scripts/myScript1.js", function() {
    ab();
    console.log(a); //prints 1
    console.log(b); //prints 2
})
```

The strange thing, which I don't understand is, the following:
If I do the following inside `oneMoreScript.js`, I will get the same output:

```
$.getScript("scripts/myScript1.js", function() {
    console.log(a); //prints 1
    console.log(b); //prints 2
});
```

**Why are the variables in the last code example still declared?** I read that every `getScript` instruction is actually an ajax instruction and if no chache is activated (default is none, which is the case), everytime a `getScript` instruction is executed, the desired script will be loaded again from the server and be executed.

Comment: scripts are loaded on global scope

Comment: $.getScript simply inserts a `<script>` tag into your page. All the normal rules of doing so still apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
var a;
var b;

function ab() {
    a=1;
    b=2;
}
```

You have two `global` variables `a` and `b`; since they were set once in `ab()`, they will be accessible with the same values from other code too.

Comment: but with the `getScript` instruction the script is loaded again and is executed again, so `var a;` and `var b;` will be again executed ?! Why are they not undefined in `oneMoreScript.js`?

Comment: No, browser does not execute the same scripts twice or more if that was once loaded to the memory

Comment: Besides, re-declaring a variable without a value does not make it undefined in JavaScript. It will keep its old value

Comment: @MysterX yes it will, if you included it on the page twice (which is what happens when you use getScript twice..

Comment: But if you would add `console.log("hello from myScript1.js")` on the top of `myScript.js` you will get on your console two times `hello from myScript1.js`.